# NSPredicate for two arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I have a table view with two mutable arrays.

```
NSMutableArray *first = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", nil];
NSMutableArray *second = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];
```

The tableview displays a label with a and a label with 1 in first row. b and 2 in the second row. and so on.
I want to use NSPredicate for the first one.

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];
NSMutableArray *searchResults = [first filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
[tableView reloadData];
```

This works fine. The table view only shows the row with "b" if I search for "b".

But the second label is always 1.

I want to sort the second array the same way like the first array.

--> If I search for "b" searchResults array only contains b and searchResults2 only contains "2".

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is better to create a class that has all of your required properties and store instances of this class in a single array than to try and coordinate activities between two associated arrays.  Alternatively replace the second array with a dictionary whose key is the value from the first array.  Then once you have "b" you can find the associated value easily

Comment: You can synchronize the two arrays indeed, but that's clearly not the best solution (quite lines of code, and hard to read afterwards). As said @Paulw11, it's better to change the architecture of how your dataSource.

Comment: For my project it would be much easier the way I described it above.
If I want to sort one array alphabetic I can sort another array the same way.

`NSMutableArray *combined = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < dataArrayt.count; i++) {
        [combined addObject: @{@"name" : arrayFirst[i], @"time": arraySecond[i]}];}
    [combined sortUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];
    arraySecond = [combined valueForKey:@"time"];`
Sth like this must also work for NSPredicate...

Comment: Then `NSArray *filteredArray = [combined filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@", searchText]];` Then just update your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and other methods to be prepared for a datasource of `combined` type.